Unable to Load JSON Schema References in package.json and .babelrc
I'm encountering issues with JSON schema references in my package.json and .babelrc files. Here are the details:

Error in package.json:

I'm getting the following error under the first bracket in my package.json:
Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/jscpd.json':
Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/jscpd.json':
Failed to establish a socket connection to proxies: [\"PROXY 127.0.0.1:60749\"].


I've tried downloading the schema and using it locally, but the issue persists.


Error in .babelrc:

In my .babelrc file, I have the following content:
{
    "$schema": "./babelrc.schema.json",
    "preset": ["env"]
}


However, I'm still encountering this error:
Unable to load schema from 'c:\\Julius Projects\\NODEJS & MYSQL\\MEDAASE_HEALTHCARE\\src\\routes\\babelrc.schema.json':
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\\Julius Projects\\NODEJS & MYSQL\\MEDAASE_HEALTHCARE\\src\\routes\\babelrc.schema.json'.




Attempted Solutions:

I followed advice to create local files (package.schema.json and babelrc.schema.json), but the error persists.



Could someone please help me understand what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them? Thank you!

Can you explain why you need the schema in your package.json?  What are you trying to accomplish?

It looks a VS Code error. The package.json error because VS Code was load that file to parse, because you offline, so you get this error. This error maybe solve on connect to Internet correctly.
The second error, please try reload the VS Code, or problem of that json file wrong.
The error is not effect you use and develop. Because that schema not need on development. The development may needn't that schema. So it is needn't to fix it.
Please give more background, thanks. If you asking in non-vscode place, please tell me  what please using and that how effect you use. About local file please give the more information.
Failed to establish a socket connection to proxies: [\"PROXY 127.0.0.1:60749\"].

This error maybe you using a wrong proxy server, please check do you set proxy server. If set, please close it.
